# Credit calculator generates wrong output

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator, currency

I need to calculate the minimum fixed monthly payment needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months. The right answer should be 310, but I get 340. I was editing code for a few hours, yet didn't find any suitable solution. What is wrong here? How is it possible to fix it?

```
balance = 3329
annualInterestRate = 0.2
payment = 10

def year_balance(init_payment, init_balance):
    """ Calculates total debt after 12 months """
    interest_sum = 0
    for month in range(12):
        # balance after monthly payment
        unpaid = init_balance - init_payment 
        # monthly interest of remaining balance
        interest = unpaid * (annualInterestRate / 12.0) 
        interest_sum += interest
    yearly = init_balance + interest_sum # total debt after 12 months
    return yearly

total = year_balance(payment, balance) # total debt after 12 months

while total - payment * 12 > 0: 
# checks if payment is big enough to fully repay the credit after 12 months 
    payment += 10

print "Lowest payment: ", payment
```

Comment: The code you provide gives an error- did you mean to change `interest_total = 0` to `interest_sum = 0`?

Comment: It looks like you're not calculating the total anew each time you adjust the payment. Since your code compounds interest monthly, you should recalculate the total each time the payment changes.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, I've revised the code

Comment: There is a huge problem here, did you ever try to change the value of `payment` ? I did and everytime the result is same = `340`. So something wrong on your function logic.

Comment: @sacma That's only if you change the value of payment to something below 340. see the last few lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to run the balance count function for each new payment amount, since the interest sum will be smaller for bigger payments. So

```
balance = 3329
annualInterestRate = 0.2
payment = 10


def year_balance(init_payment, init_balance):
    """ Calculates total debt after 12 months """
    interest_sum = 0
    unpaid = init_balance
    for month in range(12):
        # balance after monthly payment
        unpaid -= init_payment
        # monthly interest of remaining balance
        unpaid += unpaid * (annualInterestRate / 12.0)
    return unpaid

while year_balance(payment, balance) > 0:
    payment += 10

print("Lowest payment: ", payment)
```

Note: this is in case you make a payment before the credit period began. If you've done that after a month, you should first add monthly interest rate.

Comment: So my function didn't run for each new payment amount because there was no variable to set balance to initial value?

Comment: You called your function only once with initial payment, that's it

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need iteration to compute the monthly repayments. Instead, you could use the closed-form solution:

```
loan_amount = 3329
annual_interest_rate = 0.2
monthly_repayment = ((loan_amount * annual_interest_rate / 12.) /
                     (1 - (1 + annual_interest_rate / 12.) ** -12))
print monthly_repayment
```

This assumes monthly repayments and monthly compounding. For the general formulas see, for example, [here](https://www.easycalculation.com/mortgage/loan-payment-amount.php).